# CakePhp find doesn't fetch hasMany relationships

Tags: cakephp, find, has-many

I've got these simple models:

```
// ActivityLog
class ActivityLog extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'ActivityLog';

    public $useTable = "activity_logs";

    public $hasMeny = array("ActivityLogMedia");

}

// ActivityLogMedia
class ActivityLogMedia extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'ActivityLogMedia';

    public $useTable = "activity_logs_media";

    public $belongsTo = array('ActivityLog','Media');

}

// Media
class Media extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Media';

    public $useTable = "media";

    public $hasMeny = "ActivityLogMedia";

}
```

when I try to do this find:

```
$this->ActivityLog->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('ActivityLog.id' => $ret['ActivityLog']['id']),
    'recursive' => 2
));
```

Cake doesn't return any ActivityLog associated models.
Can anybody give me an explanation and/or a solution?

Comment: PS: if I perform the find on the ActivityLogMedia model, I receive all the associated models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, `$hasMeny` should be `$hasMany`.